# How to use regex to specify a series of patterns that are logically this or this or this or this?

Tags: regex, sed

One can write the regex pattern `[gH8/]+` to specify one or more of g, or H, or 8 or slash.

One can write `[{d0,d1,d2,a0,a1,a2,sp}]+` to specify one or more of the words `d0`, or `d1`, or `d2`, or `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, and `sp`.

I would like to write a pattern that contains series of patterns that are `or'd`.

Below are candidate strings.

```
0000087C                   _ActualCoNTRoLCCDREFerenceReaD   DS.B    640
00000006 0040              _CoNTRoLCCDHorizontalPIXelsPhysicalRange DC.W    $0040
00000010 4F46 4600         _.S6:    DC.B    'OFF',0
000006EA 0000 0014       R _NewCoNTRoLCCDSPeed  DC.L    _.S7_nccdsp
0000000E 0000 0032       R  DC.L    _ActualCoNTRoLCCDHorizontalPIXels
```

I don't want to capture these other types of strings that contain underscores

```
00000008 0418               DC.W    $0418
?v_x_d  267,_CoNTRoLCCDREFerenceReaDAccess,'CoNTRoLCCDREFerenceReaDAccess'
XDEF    _ActualCoNTRoLCCDShiftOUT
_ActualCoNTRoLCCDBINning                           CoNTRoLCCDData:00000064
```

Here is my first attempt to capture these strings as 'sed -nre' patterns.

```
# 8 hex digits, followed by one or more spaces, followed by underscore
/[0-9A-F]{8}\s+_/p
# 8 hex digits followed by one or more spaces, followed by
#    4 hex digits, followed by one or more spaces, followed by underscore
/[0-9A-F]{8}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+_/p
# 8 hex digits followed by one or more spaces, followed by
#    4 hex digits, followed by one or more spaces, followed by
#    4 hex digits, followed by one or more R,
#    followed by one or more spaces, followed by underscore
/[0-9A-F]{8}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+R+\s+_/p
# 8 hex digits followed by one or more spaces, followed by
#    4 hex digits, followed by one or more spaces, followed by
#    4 hex digits, followed by one or more R,
#    followed by one or more spaces, followed by one or more
#    'any' character, followed by underscore
/[0-9A-F]{8}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+R+\s+D.+_/p
```

Is it possible to combine the patterns into one pattern? Is it worth the effort for performance to combine the patterns into one pattern, or is the combination just an academic exercise?

Comment: I don't know of any regex implementation where `[{d0,d1,d2,a0,a1,a2,sp}]` works the way you claim it does, perhaps you are thinking of `(d0|d1|d2|a0|a1|a2|sp)`?

Comment: As you only want lines containing an `_`, why don't you use something like `/^(.*?_.*?)$/m`?

Comment: Or more simply, `/_/`, since it doesn't appear that matching the entire line with the regex is a requirement.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing? You want to match *only* anything following any one of those patterns? If so, `([0-9A-F]{8}\s+_)|([0-9A-F]{8}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+_)|([0-9A-F]{8}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+R+\s+_)|([0-9A-F]{8}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+[0-9A-F]{4}\s+R+\s+D.+_)`.

Comment: @F.J I using Python for the [{d0,d1,... and it seems to work.

Comment: @F.J I have added a few more examples of lines containing underscores that I don't want to match. I also don't want to match any C/C++ source code that might contain an underscore. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the **best** solution for your problem, but this solves your problem the way you were attempting initially.  Each group after `[0-9A-F]{8}` can be wrapped in `()?` to make that section optional.  The only thing to note is the `()` will create matching groups (this should be fine, by your example).

```
/[0-9A-F]{8}(\s+[0-9A-F]{4})?(\s+[0-9A-F]{4})?(\s+R+)?(\s+D)?.+_/
```

Now if you are just looking for an 8-digit hex followed by a string that contains a `_`, you can reduce that to a cleaner version:

```
/^[0-9A-F]{8}.*_.*$/
```

Note that I put a `^` and `$` to check from beginning to end, and used `.*_.*` to match the whole string that contains a `_` somewhere in it.  If you don't care to match the whole string, that can be even simpler with:

```
/[0-9A-F]{8}[^_]+_/
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/gT1cM3

Comment: You need to modify this first pattern to: `[0-9A-F]{8}(\s+[0-9A-F]{4})?(\s+[0-9A-F]{4})?(\s+R+)?(\s+D)?[^_]+_` for it to work properly. Otherwise it takes anything up to the last occurrence of a `_`.

Comment: @Sam Sullivan According to this SuperUser exchange Q&A sed does not support \d. http://superuser.com/questions/513412/sed-regex-digits. The pattern matching stopped working for me when I used \d for 0-9. \d is for perl, no?

Comment: @KeithSmith my bad, I didn't notice you were using sed.  `\d` = `0-9`, correct.  Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From just a syntactical point of view, you may easily combine them into one pattern.
The way you wrote the regexes in your question you can see that from expression to expression they *build up on each other*. For example your first expression `[0-9A-F]{8}\s+_` exists in all subsequent expressions and so on.

Knowing this you can make each subsequent expression optional by creating groups and appending `?`:

```
/[0-9A-F]{8}\s+([0-9A-F]{4}\s+)?([0-9A-F]{4}\s+R+\s+)?(D.+)?_/p
```

**Note**: this is only possible because you specified the `-r` parameter. If for some reason you have to take this parameter away you have to restructure your regex and use `(x|)` instead of `x?`.

Concerning the performance, I would say that this regex should be faster than four independent regexes with one of them being the single expression above.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `_\w+`? Matches an underscore followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, and from what you've shown that's all that's needed. You may even be able to get away with just `_`..